# Microsoft Graph: Finding all Mailboxes which belongs to a single user

Tags: c#, web-services, microsoft-graph-api

I have the following situation:

- I have written a webservice, this webservice has to read the mails from the users of my organisation
- I am using Microsoft Graph and i am using "ClientSecretCredentail" in order to log in "as an app"
- I have access to all mailboxes via my App and I can read the mails from any user
- Some users have access to more then one mailbox, by example "user_a@myorganisation.com" has additional access to "info@myorganisation.com". In Outlook I can see the inbox of "user_a" and also of "info". This connection has been made by the admin from the organisation.
- My App can read both mailboxes, no problem, because we have set the permissions to "Mail.Read".

What I need is the information, that the "user_a" has access to "info", so that I can automatically deliver the mails from both mailboxes. I can not find any list or collection with this info.

Comment: Additional Info: In the past we used the "Exchange Web Services" and this services had a collection called "AlternateMailboxes" and this exactly what I am looking for in Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [otherMailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)?

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName,otherMails
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried the "other Mailboxes", but these are not the same as the "AlternateMailboxes".

It seems, that the only way to get the "AlternateMailboxes" are by using the Powershell.